# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED while trying to connect to a websocket in python3.7

Tags: ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, python-3.7

Here is what I am trying to run

```
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://open.rocket.chat/sockjs/websocket',
                                header=["User-Agent: MyProgram", "x-custom: header"],
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close,
                                on_ping=on_ping
                                )
        ws.run_forever()
```

When I run the code I get this error from the on_error function:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)
```

I am running the code on macOS, python3.7

the requirements include:

```
websocket==0.2.1
websocket-client==0.58.0
```

The solution I tried before was adding the headers above, it worked in a Windows and linux environment, but not in a macOS.

Another thing I tried is to turn off the ssl verification like so `export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0` 
, this did not work as well.

Can you please explain the reason behind this error, and why is it inconsistent?
Sometimes it works sometimes it does not!
I want to understand the reason to be able to solve it for good.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A lot of Python packages use the root-CA certificates included in the [`certifi`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) package. Not sure if this also applies to websocket/websocket-client. But I would recommend to update the `certifi` package using pip as a first step.

Comment: @Robert I actually have the latest version in my requirements certifi==2020.12.5 I tried and reinstalled it with no luck.

Comment: Answered Here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010288/why-do-i-get-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-in-python-when-ssl-setup-looks-ok/75469539#75469539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for MacOS.

All you need to do is to navigate to `Applications/Python 3.x`

and run this file `Install Certificates.command`